# xUnit tests don't show up when Active solution platform is x64

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, xunit.net

I have Visual Studio Pro 2015 and I'm trying to run xUnit tests in my solution.  When I compile with Active solution platform set to "Any cpu" all my tests show up in Test Explorer.  If I switch to x64 and rebuild (successfully), none of them show up in Test Explorer.  Is this some kind of limitation of xUnit?  I haven't found anything to that effect online.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/31662663/11635 I assume - the runner runs either x86 or x64, so if you build it to be specific, you need the runner to be in aligment with what you're compiling to

Comment: That fixed my problem.  You can make your comment the answer to my question.

Comment: I have but would also be happy to see the question closed unless you believe your question is significantly more searchable than the original...

Comment: I just searched for my problems using the terms that I would naturally use and this popped up as the first result, but  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571699/how-do-i-get-unit-tests-to-run-on-a-x64-platform/31662663#31662663 was much further down, so I think it's useful to leave this one here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31662663/11635), the runner runs either x86 or x64, so if you build it to be specific, you need the runner to be in aligment with what you're compiling to:- [image: bittedness menu option in Test menu],