# Unit test coverage using dotCover command line tool(JetBrains) - Is it possible to run this tool with x64 dll tests?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, code-coverage, jetbrains-ide, dotcover

I am using dotCover command line tool(JetBrains) https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/download/#section=commandline

I was reading this documentation
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html

I have a logic dll - x64 compiled.
I have a tests dll (AppTests Test project) -x64 compiled
I was creating coverage.xml on my solution Items folder with the parameters below

```
<AnalyseParams>
      <TargetExecutable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</TargetExecutable> 
      <TargetArguments>D:\Projects\TheApplication\bin\Debug\AppTests.dll</TargetArguments>
      <Output>AppCoverageReport.html</Output>
      <ReportType>html</ReportType>
</AnalyseParams>
```

From the cmd I am typing "dotcover analyse coverage.xml"

I am getting the flowing Error:
"If you build your test project assembly as a 64 bit assembly, it cannot be loaded. When you build your test project assembly, select "Any CPU" for the platform. To run your tests in 64 bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your tests in a 32 bit process"

I can't build my logic.dll and AppTests.dll to "any cpu".

I read this post:
[How do I get unit tests to run on a x64 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571699/how-do-i-get-unit-tests-to-run-on-a-x64-platform?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But in my case, I am running the tests from dot cover command line tool and not from the visual studio UI.

What can I do? Is there any other option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting answer from Resharper support and it solve my issue, so I am sharing it.

```
<AnalyseParams>
     <TargetExecutable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe</TargetExecutable> 
     <TargetArguments>D:\Projects\TheApplication\bin\Debug\AppTests.dll /Settings:"<your path>\runsetting.xml"</TargetArguments>
     <Output>AppCoverageReport.html</Output>
     <ReportType>html</ReportType>
</AnalyseParams>
```